# Meaning of Monit status codes

Tags: status, monit

I need a way to find out what every monit xml status code means. I have some xml output which is in this format:

https://gist.github.com/plasticbrain/54ceaf101168d20f9a90

Or in case the link doesn't work, this:

```
<services>
        <service name="system">
            <type>5</type>
            <collected_sec>1414691061</collected_sec>
            <collected_usec>254769</collected_usec>
            <status>0</status>
            <status_hint>0</status_hint>
            <monitor>1</monitor>
            <monitormode>0</monitormode>
            <pendingaction>0</pendingaction>
</service>
```

Within this code block we can see:

```
<status> 0 </status>
```

I've googled a lot to find a complete list of all possible codes and their meanings but I've been unable to find anything so far. The monit documentation does not appear to mention it at all either.

Comment: Hey. Did you by any chance get the answer for this?

Comment: I would like to know if you got an answer ...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, while I may have, it's been so long ago I don't recall. I no longer have access to the code so I can't verify I found an answer.